# How do you name Axios Interceptors for exjection in Vue.js components?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, interceptor, axios

I am using Vue CLI to load an instance property for Axios. I have added a couple of interceptors and I will like the ability to turn them off when using the Axios instance from inside a Vue component.

In the documentation Axios suggests you just label the interceptor then `eject` is later via the name.

```
var myInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(function () {/*...*/});
axios.interceptors.request.eject(myInterceptor);
```

So the issue I am having, is that I can't figure out who I can name my interceptor for use in components.

Here is my setup:

*api-client.js*

```
import axios from 'axios'

var client = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_DOMAIN,
  headers: { Accept: 'application/json' }
})

var unauthorizedInterceptor = client.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  return response
}, function (error) {

  ...

  return Promise.reject(error)
})

export default client
```

*main.js*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import apiClient from './api-client'

Vue.prototype.$apiClient = apiClient

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
})
```

*component.js*

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      username: null,
      email: null,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateAccount () {
      var self = this

      var data = {
        username: this.username,
        email: this.email,
        first_name: this.firstName,
        last_name: this.lastName
      }

      self.$apiClient`enter code here`.interceptors.request.eject(unauthorizedInterceptor) // Remove interceptor here.

      self.$apiClient.patch('/me')
      .then(function () {
        ...
      })
      .catch(function () {
        ...
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

How could I name the interceptor to eject it at the component level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export the interceptor from your `api-client.js` and import it where you want to eject it.

**api-client.js**

```
export let unauthorizedInterceptor = ...
export default client
```

**component.js**

```
import { unauthorizedInterceptor } from "./api-client"

...
self.$http.interceptors.request.eject(unauthorizedInterceptor)
```

You may want to export the interceptor function itself as well so that you could add it back if needed.

Alternatively export a function or two that can do this management for you.

**api-client.js**

```
let unauthorizedInterceptor

export function removeUnauthorizedInterceptor() {
    axios.interceptors.request.eject(unauthorizedInterceptor)
}

export function addUnauthorizedInterceptor(){
    unauthorizedInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(...)
}
```

**component.js**

```
import { removeUnauthorizedInterceptor} from "./api-client"
removeUnauthorizedInterceptor()
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for the tip on the management functions as well!